# no such table found in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

im having a problem trying to establish a database in android, everytime i log in, the log cat says that no such table.

```
public class DatabaseOnline extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "name";

private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "online";


private static final String KEY_ID = "Registration_id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
private static final String KEY_UNIQUEID = "unique_id";

public DatabaseOnline(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
            + KEY_NAME + " VARCHAR (255), " + KEY_PASSWORD
            + " VARCHAR (255), " + KEY_ID + " VARCHAR(255), "
            + KEY_UNIQUEID + " VARCHAR (255)" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
}



public void addUser(String name, String password, String regId,
        String unique_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password); // Email
    values.put(KEY_ID, regId);
    values.put(KEY_UNIQUEID, unique_id);
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}


public int getRowCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    // return row count
    return rowCount;
}

/**
 * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void resetTables() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
    db.close();
}

}
```

the problem is when i log in:

```
    DatabaseOnline db = new DatabaseOnline(getApplicationContext());
db.getWritableDatabase();
JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

System.out.println("unique id " + json_user.getString("unique_id"));
System.out.println("password " + json_user.getString("password"));
  db.addUser(json_user.getString("name"),json_user.getString("password"),json_user.getString("regId"),json_user.getString("unique_id"));                                                   

Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main.class);
dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(dashboard);
finish();
```

what appears is that android didnt create the database. 
and here is the log cat:

```
11-20 21:42:15.162: E/SQLiteLog(1176): (1) no such table: online
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176): Error inserting unique_id=50a939dc9fa8a4.09780382 Name=v Registration_id=APA91bHnScWAF0xjtMjyHTvHx3ON6Eu_8on6kZUL5EvDmtAK8WDxwBVpNyMoapaTl0-ProAnY0m9VZbS-0OPeMshQkeU7ZOHlfI8tUAVJbeIgoe9sdL061ntJ8MnyglrLHK2BOWH2K1n Password=9e3669d19b675bd57058fd4664205d2a
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: online (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO online(unique_id,Name,Registration_id,Password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176):     at guc.edu.i.DatabaseOnline.addUser(DatabaseOnline.java:66)
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176):     at guc.edu.i.Login.login(Login.java:199)
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176):     at guc.edu.i.Login$7.run(Login.java:146)
11-20 21:42:15.282: E/SQLiteDatabase(1176):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: The shift key doesn't have anything to do with the title; it has everything to do with the body of your question.  Please respect our site and its members by using proper capitalization and punctuation in your writing, and provide a coherent title so that people searching Google for similar problems don't get confused.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is this the first time the database is being created? try changing

`private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;`

to

`private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;`

That would cause the Table to be created and should sort out the issue

Comment: Why does this work?  Is there something in the (not seen here) superclass that interprets this Version field as some sort of magic number?

Comment: @RobertHarvey incrementing the DB version in a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper typically forces the database schema to be rebuilt. This is worked for OmAr (whose shift key seems to be erRatiC rather than non-functional) because he added the "online" table in his Java String but didn't know to update the SQL schema...

Answer (score 0):

If you make changes to your database then clearing the cache & clearing the data from your device (settings->Apps->your App) will also solve this problem.
I have tried it & its working.