# Android Getter and Setter in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi im beginner only to android and I want to retrieve data in my external sqlite. I dont have any idea how to use Getter and Setter in my databasehelper so i can retrieve the data from table. Need your help guys.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.jathniel.displayname/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "mydoctorfinder.sqlite";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private Context myContext = null;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, (SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory) null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = this.checkDataBase();
        if(!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                this.copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error");
            }
        }
    }

    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = this.myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        FileOutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int length;
        while((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String e = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(e, (SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)null, 0);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            ;
        }

        if(checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null;
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        this.myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, (SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)null, 0);
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if(this.myDataBase != null) {
            this.myDataBase.close();
        }

        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public void createDatabase() {
    }
}
```

Comment: would recommend using `Firebase` as its easy NoSQL scalable database, from a beginner perspective its easy :)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/13481356/1618363, it has a similar SQLite data access

Comment: i cant use firebase @oblivion because the app should be access also if the device is not connected to internet